# How to write/change a visio file with java (jacob)

Tags: java, com, visio, jacob

I wasn't able to find anything useful about how to write a visio file with java, and probably looked through every article on the web.
If found a lot of stuff about doing it with c#, vb, and other stuff but couldn't find what I need.

I also found this, but I am not sure if this (reverse engineering) could do what I need  >>[How to generate MS Visio diagram automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000107/how-to-generate-ms-visio-diagram-automatically)<<. Because I really want to create a vsd file with my java application write a lot of data into it (from an xml file for example) and open it afterwards with visio to check and correct that data.

It took me a while to find this

> > http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java/Development/jacob-1.15/com/jacob/samples/visio/Catalogvisio.htm <<
> >     which at least allowed me to open a visio file.

**But I still need to know how to write into that file and save it afterwards.**

So in short, my acutal attempt is to use jacob, but I don't know how to do stuff like "add block at position x,y" with that com bridge. Is there a docu for that stuff?

any help would be appreciated

thanks

Comment: try searching for "java jacob visio" -- there do seem to be some examples on the web.

Comment: there are some examples, but they only show how to get a connection to visio and open it with a file. I haven't found how to edit a visio file through that connection by code. Have I missed something you found?
I guess I'm missing the right dispatch command.
for example instead of "Export" I'd need something like add rectangle...
ActiveXComponent document = new ActiveXComponent(getProperty("ActivePage").toDispatch());
      Variant[] args = new Variant[1];
      args[0] = new Variant(f.getPath());
      document.invoke("Export", args);