# How to make the most logical/clear diagram layout on Visio?

Tags: diagram, visio

I have a workflow diagram that I've been modifying a lot and as a result it's suffered in clarity. It's formed of several objects representing states joined by arrows and connectors.

***I was wondering is there an automatic way to create a diagrams from a 'net list' of the connections that need to be made? Or is there a standard way to create a logical diagram like this without overlapping connectors/unnecessary complexity?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a visual representation of a "net list" is often referred to as "graph layout". There are many tools which allow you to do this. Visio is a bit limited here (it supports basic automatic layout for "orgchart" diagrams out of the box though).

Note that Visio also provides re-layout options for the already-existing drawing (you can find them under "Design" tab, "Re-layout page"). These allow one to change the layout of the current diagram. Maybe that's what you are looking for.

Similar question about automatic layout here:
[How to generate MS Visio diagram automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000107/how-to-generate-ms-visio-diagram-automatically)